# 'focus' listener not calling every time. React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native technology. I have used following hierarchy in my react native app.

1. I have used Stack.Navigator in which I am using various screen, I. Login, II. Sign-Up, III. TabBar Screen.
2. In TabBar screen I have used various individual Stack.Navigator because I have to show tab bar on every child screen.
3. Now problem is that I have to update some value on tab screen when user click on that particular screen. It is calling once at first time, not working second time.

I have used following code for execute 'focus' listener on tab screen :-

```
  onScreenFocus = () => {
     this.reloadFavrouite()
     alert("again calling")
 }

 componentDidMount() {
     this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () =>     this.onScreenFocus())
     this.reloadFavrouite()
 }
```

'focus' listener work well If I am not use individual Stack.Navigator at every tab screen, but it is creating another issue is that tab bar not showing in child screen.

I have used this tab navigator code:- Please check

```
export default class TabNavigator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName='Home' lazy={true} tabBarOptions={
                {
                    style: {
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                        borderTopLeftRadius: 25,
                        borderTopRightRadius: 25,
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        borderColor: 'transparent',
                    }
                }
            }>
                <Tab.Screen name="HomeNavigator" component={HomeNavigator} 
                    options={{

                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
                            const tintColortab = focused ? "#006C35"
                                : "#000000"
                            return (
                                <Text style={{ color: tintColortab, fontSize: 8, fontFamily: "Roboto-Bold", marginBottom: 6 }}>{StringsOfLanguages.Home}</Text>
                            )
                        },

                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            const tintColortab = focused ? "#006C35"
                                : "#000000"
                            return (
                                <Image source={require('../../../assets/images/TabBarIcons/ic_home_selected/ic_home_selected.png')}
                                    style={{ marginTop: 10, tintColor: tintColortab }}>
                                </Image>

                            )
                        }
                    }}>         
                </Tab.Screen>
                <Tab.Screen name="FavouriteNavigator" component={FavouriteNavigator}
                    options={{
                        tabBarLabel: ({ focused }) => {
                            
                            const tintColortab = focused ? "#006C35"
                                : "#000000"
                            return (
                                <Text style={{ color: tintColortab, fontSize: 8, fontFamily: "Roboto-Bold", marginBottom: 6 }}>{StringsOfLanguages.Favorite}</Text>
                            )
                        },
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                            const tintColortab = focused ? "#006C35"
                                : "#000000"
                            return (
                                <Image source={require('../../../assets/images/TabBarIcons/ic_favorits_unselected/ic_favorite_unselected.png')}
                                    style={{ marginTop: 10, tintColor: tintColortab }}>
                                </Image>
                            )
                        }
                    }}
                >        
                </Tab.Screen>
            </Tab.Navigator>
        );
    }
```

And individual navigation is like :-

```
class HomeNavigator extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="AllRestuarent" component={AllRestuarent} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="AllLaundry" component={AllLaundry} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="AllEntertainment" component={AllEntertainment} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Offer" component={Offer} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="ComponyMap" component={ComponyMap} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                </Stack.Navigator>

            </NavigationContainer>

        );
    }
}

class FavouriteNavigator extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="Offer" component={Offer} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                    <Stack.Screen name="ComponyMap" component={ComponyMap} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
                </Stack.Navigator>

            </NavigationContainer>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: react-navigation version ?

Comment: I have used like it :-  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.13.0",

Comment: @PankajSonava not sure to understand what you problem is, do you want to show the tab on each nested stacked screen ? or is it about the focus listener ?

Comment: @GChevass, I have added complete code please check

Answer (score 0):

You are not using focus listener in the right way according to your current version, You are using react-navigation v5 and you are adding a listener the way it is used in react-navigation v4, Here is a solution to your problem.

```js
class YourClassComopnent extends React.Component {
      componentDidMount() {

        /* 
           Now you can access to isFocused prop and 
           this prop will be true whenever your screen is
           in the focus.
        */ 

        if(this.props.isFocused) this.onScreenFocus()
        this.reloadFavrouite()
      }
      render() {

        // Get it from props

        const { isFocused } = this.props;
      }
    }
    
    // Wrap and export
    export default function(props) {
      const isFocused = useIsFocused();
       // pass your class here
      return <YourClassComopnent {...props} isFocused={isFocused} />;
    }
```

[Link to docs, how you can use isFocused in react-navigation v5](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-is-focused/#using-with-class-component)

Comment: But same thing is working if I use single screen to tab bar instead of navigation

Comment: `this.props.navigation.addListener` is still available inside a navigation prop but it's not recommended to use with v5